# PyRun_SimpleString is blocking whenever import is used, never returns

Tags: python, c++, cpython

```
std::cout << "im in here!\n";
PyGILState_STATE sMain = PyGILState_Ensure();

if (sMain)
{
    std::cout << "attempting\n";
    PyRun_SimpleString("import sys; sys.exit();");
    std::cout << "attempted!\n";
}

PyGILState_Release(sMain);
```

Seems attempted never prints however sMain is valid and exists
PyRun_SimpleString never appears to return at all actually. Python code in question never appears to run either.

Edit:
So i've narrowed the problem down to whenever I import a module in the string.
Normal code works fine however if I import  the function blocks and never returns

Comment: Time to use your debugger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it, tried importing with PyImport_ImportModuleNoBlock and it reported that the module lock was held by another thread *Python 2.7*